I want to integrate my JSF managed bean with Spring bean
Problem Description: I am using @autowired annotation in my JSF bean but getting null, sharing my JSF Bean and rest code. i am also using primefaces omega theme.
JSF Bean

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private User user;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImp;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    
    
    public void login() {
        
        //UserService userservice = SpringContext.getBean(UserService.class);

        System.out.println("In LoginBean in " + username + " Password " + password);
// GEtting null in below
        user = userServiceImp.findByUsername(username);
    }
    // getters and setters

}


My Spring Bean
@Service
@Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
}

My Pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.hbl.mfb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bisp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>Bisp</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>  or the version compatible with your
            project 
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version> <!-- or the version compatible with your
            project -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI Impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-jsf</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7.Final</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- CDI required APIs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Oracle JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>de.rototor.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>graphics2d</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
                    <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version> <!-- or the latest version available -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot parent -->


        <!-- Spring Boot starter web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.hbl.mfb.MainApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>web.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>

            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.36.v20210114</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/Bisp</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>distribute</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>

            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-layout</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/assemble/layout.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <finalName>
                                        ${project.name}-layout-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-theme</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/assemble/theme.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <finalName>
                                        ${project.name}-theme-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>
                                ${project.name}-theme-${project.version}-jakarta</finalName>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <shadeSourcesContent>true</shadeSourcesContent>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>
                                            org/primefaces/${project.name}/component/*</include>
                                        <include>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</include>
                                        <include>META-INF/faces-config.xml</include>
                                        <include>
                                            META-INF/primefaces-${project.name}.taglib.xml</include>
                                        <include>
                                            META-INF/resources/primefaces-${project.name}-*/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jakarta</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                    <shadedClassifierName>jakarta</shadedClassifierName>
                                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="io.yupiik.maven.shade.transformer.RelocationTransformer">
                                            <delegates>
                                                <transformer
                                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
                                                <transformer
                                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                                    <resource>
                                                        META-INF/faces-config.xml</resource>
                                                </transformer>
                                                <transformer
                                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                                    <resource>
                                                        META-INF/primefaces-${project.name}.taglib.xml</resource>
                                                </transformer>
                                            </delegates>
                                        </transformer>
                                    </transformers>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>
                                                ${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                    <relocations>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.faces</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.faces</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.el</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.el</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.annotation</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.annotation</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.servlet</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.servlet</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.persistence</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.persistence</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.enterprise</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.enterprise</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.xml.bind</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.xml.bind</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.validation</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.validation</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.inject</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.inject</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.activation</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.activation</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.ws.rs</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.ws.rs</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.jws</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.jws</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.cache</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.cache</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.xml.ws</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.xml.ws</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>javax.xml.soap</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>jakarta.xml.soap</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>window.jsf</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>window.faces</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                        <relocation>
                                            <pattern>jsf.ajax</pattern>
                                            <shadedPattern>faces.ajax</shadedPattern>
                                        </relocation>
                                    </relocations>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>io.yupiik.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-shade-transformers</artifactId>
                                <version>0.0.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <!--<webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</warSourceDirectory>
                            <webXml>${project.build.directory}/web.xml</webXml>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


i need a solution, please let me know where i am wrong?
I can share further code if needed as well.
I tried @component annotation also other different methods i found on google but still getting null.

You have multiple options. @Inject @ManagedProperty, SpringBeanAutowiringSupport or a custom CDI Extension. See abovelinked duplicate for detailed examples on all of them.
